# Running scraper bot on remote server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to run python script which uses selenium on remote linux server?
I would like to connect via ssh, upload the script and have it working 24/7.
But I am not sure if such script which normally is based on interacting with browser would work.
This script logins to facebook and then do some stuff which help me with my work and I would like to put it on remote server so I don't have to run my pc all thetime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely doable, what u need can be simplified to:

- your scraper script (python is installed on some Unix machines, so no
  need to worry about the runtime environment)
- cron job ([CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server if you need some more complex behavior)
- selenium driver binaries
- [Xvfb](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless) setup
- (optional) some `deploy.sh` that will automatically put your new code versions on the VM